# Multiple dropdowns to form a request

Tags: php, jquery, dropdown

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am trying to integrate a semi-smart system for reporting purposes on our activities on Google AdWords;

I am trying to integrate this system in our custom CRM.

The idea, would be that of having multiple dropdown which help form a sentence which will basically be a request you are making and then returning the answer to this request.

For example:

(What) (Where) where (Metric) (When) (Compare to?)

All these would be dropdowns and would be creating a sentence when chosen. For example:

Product AdGroups in X-FR* where Cost is over 10% from 10th of March to 10th of April

*X-FR would be my AdWords account for the French market

Basically, each dropdown would have multiple answers but not all answers can be used with the previous dropdown.

I’m trying to make it so this thing makes as much sense as possible but I’ll admit it is not easy.

What I’m trying to figure out and where I need your help is, if you can envision what I also do, how would you go about coding this? Do I need to assign an ID to each of the answers possible for Each dropdown, and then create some arrays of possible chains? For example

If Product is 001, X-FR is 032, Cost is 077, over is 102, etc… then you basically map out all of the possible solutions like “ [001,032,077,102,…] = this answer”?

Any other idea of where something similar (kind of like a tree) is being used?

Please note I have basic dev knowledge, I’m not a professional, and I will have a team working on this with me.

Thanks a lot in advance,
-Mathieu

Comment: if there are rules about which selections are allowed, based on earlier selections, then yes you'll need to define those rules in code if you want the application to enforce them. And every time the user makes a selection you'll have to check the selection against the rules (and of course you can change the UI to make invalid selections impossible, but in a web environment you must always double-check the input at the server-side when the query is submitted, because malicious users can use the browser developer tools to alter or bypass the HTML controls).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
function get_select_value_array(){
  var select_arr=[];
  $('select').each(function(){
 var this_id=$(this).attr('id');
 var this_val=$(this).val();
 if(this_id=='Product'){
  select_arr[0]=this_val;
 }else if(this_id=='X-FR'){
  select_arr[1]=this_val;
 }else if(this_id=='Cost'){
  select_arr[2]=this_val;
 }
  });
  return select_arr;
}

 function compare_arrays(_arr1, arr2){
   return ($(_arr1).not(arr2).length === 0 && $(arr2).not(_arr1).length === 0);
 }

 var etalon_arr=["001", "032", "077"];
 var select_arr=get_select_value_array();

 /* console.log(etalon_arr, select_arr);*/

 if(compare_arrays(select_arr, etalon_arr)){
  console.log('Is Good!!!');
 }
```

```css
       div{
         display:inline-block;
         border-style:solid;
         border-width:2px;
         border-color:gray;
         padding:10px;
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <div>
     <select id="Product">
        <option value="001">Product 001</option>
        <option value="002">Product 002</option>
        <option value="003">Product 003</option>
     </select>
   </div>

   <div>
     <select id="X-FR">
        <option value="032">X-FR 032</option>
        <option value="033">X-FR 033</option>
        <option value="034">X-FR 034</option>
     </select>
   </div>

   <div>
     <select id="Cost">
        <option value="077">Cost 077</option>
        <option value="078">Cost 078</option>
        <option value="079">Cost 079</option>
     </select>
   </div>
```